# FFMPEG : Microphone capturing too much noise while using ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I am listening audio from source IP address and trying to encode it into speex format and again sending it to the destination IP address using ffmpeg.

My ffmpeg command is:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i temp.sdp -c:a libspeex -f rtp rtp://<dest_ip>:<port>
```

SDP file content is(temp.sdp):

```
v=0 
c=IN IP4 <source_IP>
t=0 0
m=audio <port> RTP/AVP 98
a=rtpmap:98 L16/8000
```

Issue: Whenever I am trying to run this command, I am getting too much background noise on speaker.
I could hear music(not clearly), but not human voice.

Also, I have tried with highpass and lowpass filters are as follows:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i temp.sdp -af "highpass=f=200, lowpass=f=3000" -c:a 
    libspeex -f rtp rtp://<dest_ip>:<port>
```

Comment: Reduce the gain of the mic.

Comment: Thanks @llogan, yes it working...!!!
Actually I new in ffmpeg.